# Ping Server and Ping Client (UDP)

Tags: java, udp, ping

I am studying ping server and ping clients using UDP and I found java codes on line. http://www.daimi.au.dk/~carl/Uge6/PingClient.java
I run it using eclipse and it requires 3 arguments. What are those arguments and where should they be placed? I think the port number and the IP address are arguments but whenever I try to place them in `args[0], args[1]`, the code is still not running.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, it requires 2 arguments. Address and port. I run it like that

```
java PingClient [ADDRESS] [PORT]
```

and it works.

Maybe I misunderstood your questions. What exactly is the error?

Comment: Where should I place the address and the port? I did `int port = Integer.parseInt("9865");` for the port and `InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("<address>");` for the address. Or I will really type in `java PingClient [ADDRESS] [PORT]`? But in which part of the code? Thank you!

Comment: If you want to put address and port into the code you can write: `int port = 9865;` and `InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");`

Comment: In that case you also have to remove argument checking `if (args.length != 2) { ... }`

Comment: I'm just wondering why can't it ping other IP addresses other than my localhost?

Comment: Well, normally ping is sent using ICMP packet. This program sends UDP packets and I guess most servers block those packets on most ports. Or  you are just pinging closed ports.

Comment: So it's just normal that I get a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out` exception? Based on the ping server in the URL, some packets are blocked? Thank you much for helping me learn ping.

Answer (score 0):

you're right, you have to use an address and a port (as explain in the source code comments). There are 2 arguments, not 3.

"the code is still not running" => what happens ? An error, an exception ? Nothing ? How do you test the client and server programs ?

Comment: My problem is where to place the address and port in the code. By "the code is still not running", I mean it does not do its job yet, ie, when I run it, it says "Required arguments: port" because there's still no port number and IP adress. :)

Answer (score 0):

command line arguments are arguments that you can pass to your java class through  command line.In this case for example you should write "java PingClint www.google.com 80" in your cmd